# What information gets shared if I connect online?

Tags: kirby-and-the-forgotten-land

After starting up *Kirby and the Forgotten Land*, the game asked if I wanted to connect online to make my gameplay information visible to other players. What information gets shared if I connect online?

Comment: All I know is that the game features some present codes that require to be connected to the internet for them to work. Don't know if that's related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a Wise Waddle Dee that shows up in town and connects you online for global gameplay stats. The information seems to include world records for certain feats or the total amount of times players have done an action. The stats I've seen are:

Global count facts:

- How many Awoofies have been defeated
- How many times Waddle Dee Cafe items have been eaten globally
- How many objects have been inhaled
- How many Pop Flowers have bloomed
- Number of Star coins collected
- Number of Waddle Dees saved
- The most popular Kirby ability

World record stats:

- Solo world record times and weapon used for Arena challenges without powerups or amiibo and what
- Record time and weapon used for individual boss fights
- Weekly world record for Flash Fishing

[image: Wise waddle dee asking if we want to hear info from around the world]

Answer (score 0):

Not the full answer, just a suggestion: if you click through it will show you a EULA style confirmation that has more information about it.

Edit:

Ok here’s the screencap.

[image: eula]

Comment: There is also a [Wise Waddle Dee](https://wikirby.com/wiki/Wise_Waddle_Dee) that will show up in the town and connects online (but requires Switch Online).

Comment: @Batophobia that's actually where I got the screencap from!  Right after confirming to connect online with the NPC, it shows the screen I linked.